# 0 1 binary programming

Tags: binary, machine-code

hey guys im looking for references to learn binary programming like coding with just 0 1 ... if anyone can show me the right way or help me i would be thankful its necessary for me to learn 0 1 programming but unfortunately i couldnt find sources to learn it everybody says assembly i know but i need 0 1 not that one so please help me with that learn it.......... if any of you knows it lets keep in touch please or if you have refrences please send to me via email: mohammadaminm97@yahoo.com thanks guys

Comment: First off: There is no such thing as 0 1 binary Programming. It is called Machine Code. Secondly:Nobody, and I mean NOBODY does this unless insane. A similar question was asked here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126095/resources-on-learning-to-program-in-machine-code

Comment: i know and im insane :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you "need" to program directly in binary?

In any case, usually the reference manual a processor will give you the details of how to encode assembly instructions into binary. E.g. for the Intel 8086 processor, see pages 164 and after of https://eclass.upatras.gr/modules/document/file.php/EE649/8086_family_Users_Manual.pdf

For a modern processor this will be very complicated and is best left to an actual assembler.

Comment: to program for bios i wanna add more tools to it to make computers safe and more easy to work with i dont think assembly would help me with that